# limit url address in form submishion

Tags: php, forms, limit

i creat a form by rsform pro in joomal 2.5
i want to ban several url address in a field 
i use this code

```
    if(isset($_POST['form']['link']))
{
$bad = array('ebooks.com','suprbay.org');
if(in_array($_POST['form']['link'],$bad))
{
    $redirectLink = 'index.php?option=com_rsform&formId='.$formId;
    $RSadapter->redirect($redirectLink,'this url limited');
}
}
```

this code is true when user use exactly  "ebooks.com" or "suprbay.org" but when user use
"www.suprbay.org" or "http://www.ebooks.com/635228/you-losing-weight/roizen-michael-f-oz-mehmet-c/" or when use that plus every thing this code do not work

i went when url contain main domain that code work
please help me
thanks

Comment: On a side note, if a user is malicious they could use a url shortener like tinyurl.com to get around this restriction. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        foreach ($bad as $badsite){
            if (stristr($_POST['form']['link'],$badsite)){
                $redirectLink = 'index.php?option=com_rsform&formId='.$formId;
                $RSadapter->redirect($redirectLink,'this url limited');
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: $bad = array('ebooks.com','suprbay.org');
foreach ($bad as $badsite){
            if (strstr($_POST['form']['link'],$badsite)){
                $redirectLink = 'index.php?option=com_rsform&formId='.$formId;
                $RSadapter->redirect($redirectLink,'this url limited');
                break;
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
$value = htmlspecialchars($_POST['form']['link']); // convert special characters
// note that you should'nt use $_POST
// joomla has it's own way to get request variables
// use JFactory::getApplication('site')->input->get('form', array(), 'post', 'array');
// this will return form array which you can work with

foreach($bad as $site)
{
    if(strposi($value, $site) !== false)
    {
        // value contains one of invalid links
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the domain of a URL requires parsing it, and isn't completely trivial to do from scratch. There is a useful PHP function, [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), which will do it for you.

```
$parse_result = parse_url($_POST['form']['link']);
$link_domains = explode('.', $parse_result['host']);
$length = count($link_domains);
$link_main_domain = $link_domains[$length - 2].'.'.$link_domains[$length - 1];
```

Then you just compare `$link_main_domain` to your `$bad` array as before.

Basically `parse_url` returns (among other things) the full domain string. E.g. 'subdomain.domain.tld'. The rest of the code is just taking the last two segments of that domain.

A simpler solution would be to just search the link for the domain you want to avoid, but this doesn't account for it appearing in the URL other than in the host segment.

Remember that you can't be sure where a link goes to. It might forward someone to a 'bad' site whatever its own domain is.